# Css flex sidebar slide

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I'm trying to slide the sidebar out and pull the content across but my code only does the former. I've tried animating the content too but it keeps its width and doesn't expand.

Fairly new to flex.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqvmrP

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar open">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 900px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.sidebar.open {
  position: static;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar.closed {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  //display: none;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('open closed');
});
```

Comment: Tip&trick of the day: `open closed` classes make no sense. You only need a default state and only one special class. Not two :)

Comment: Thanks, it did originally just have the default state and special class but I was playing around with something earlier and forgot to put it back :)

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 1):

As `transform` doesn't move any other content than itself, it won't push the `content` element.

One option is to use `margin-left` to do that.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpQoXg)

Stack snippet

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 900px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  margin-left: -300px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.sidebar.open {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar">

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```